# Is there a way to bypass MS Exchange internal routing for a single imap email account?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

I have an old Windows SBS 2003 server running the built in exchange 6.5.

There are numerous issues with how the network has been set up which are preventing outlook web access and remote access which I am aware of and actually going to move email off this server and onto Web/Imap.

At the moment I have an account set up on our web hosting: email@mydomain.com which is setup in outlook as an Imap account which works all good and well except for when internal outlook clients try to email it.

I have setup a user with the email address but when you try to email it from an internal client, no email is received by the web imap account and nothing is stuck in the queue.  However if I setup the account as an exchange account I can see the email there.  It seems as though what is happening is exchange is routing the email even when I delete the SMTP entry for email@domain.local

Is there a way to tell exchange to let email for this account to just go through to the web email server as opposed to trying to route it itself?

Answer (score 1):

`Is there a way to tell exchange to let email for this account to just go through to the web email server as opposed to trying to route it itself?`

Not easily, no. Even though no mailbox or object exists with that email address Exchange is still authoritative for that email domain. Upon not finding a mailbox or an object with that email address Exchange will simply blackhole/delete it.

What you would need to do would be to setup a shared SMTP address space between Exchange and the other email server, which seems like it's probably not worth the efoort in this case.